# Defining good method of having an alias function

Tags: php, function, optimization

I need to have two functions which one is the alias of the other one because of backward compatibility issue.

```
public function getMostPopularArticles(array $params = array())
{
    $this->getMostViewedArticles($params);
}

public function getMostViewedArticles(array $params = array())
{
    return $this->_response_request(".....");
}
```

`getMostPopularArticles()` is the new function that is the alias to the older function (which in time will be removed) `getMostViewedArticles()`

Am, I doing it the right way? Any room for improvements?

I have to mention that `getMostViewedArticles()` (the old function) is using the new parameters to return the right data, but I just have to an alias with the correct name (`getMostPopularArticles()`) so users have the time needed to update their code and in a future release, remove completely the old named function.

Comment: When did PHP let you typehint for built-in types?

Comment: Typehints work for arrays as of at least PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you do :

```
public function getMostViewedArticles(array $params = array())
{
    return getMostPopularArticles($params);
}
```

This way, any new changes will only need to be done in `getMostPopularArticles` but `getMostViewedArticles` can be still used by legacy code.

Also `getMostPopularArticles` should have whatever business logic you are currently using, since that is the newer function which you want to continue using

```
public function getMostPopularArticles(array $params = array())
{
    return $this->_response_request(".....");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a deprecated function, you should essentially eschew it in all new code. When the function is deleted, your code will (obviously) break. Therefore, you should not call the deprecated function: you should instead copy and paste the code (or rewrite it) in the new call.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I apologize for not completely explaining everything, so therefor, please check my question's update